# How can I store paragraphs in mysql from a <textarea> using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Could someone please help me import and display paragraphs in my text input?

My problems are...

1. How can I get a `\n` or `<br>` to input into mysql in the first place.
2. Why doesnt `echo nl2br($row->comment);` work? I put `\n`'s into my database manually and it didn't output them. `Testing\nTesting\nTesting` came out as `"Testing\nTesting\nTesting"`.

Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT: I know there are lots of these on stackoverflow but none of them seem to explain the whole process and i'm struggling to piece it together.

Code:

```
if(isset($_POST['btn_wall'])){

  $sUsername = safeString($_SESSION['username']);
  $sWall = safeString($_POST['post_wall']);

  if($sWall != ""){
    $query = "INSERT INTO wall (user, comment, dt) VALUES (:user, :comment, now())";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(':user', $sUsername, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':comment', $sWall, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
  }
}
```

I then recreate it with:

```
<ul>
    <?php
    $query = "SELECT user, comment, dt FROM wall ORDER BY dt DESC LIMIT 6";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
    $count = $stmt->rowCount();

    if($count > 0){
      while($row = $stmt->fetchObject()){
        echo "<li>".nl2br($row->comment)." - ".$row->user."</li>";
      }
    }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You just don't need to write `\n` manually in database. In your text area, you just write as you want and it will go to database exactly as it wrote. Then when you will just echo that. The whole text will be displayed. If still there is newline missing, you can use `html_entity_decode($value)`.

Comment: How you get data out rather depends on How and What you put in in the first place

Comment: So how can I convert a paragraph to <br> before hand?

Answer (score 0):

> 1) How can I get a \n or 
>  to input into mysql in the first place.

Use the `blob` type.

> 2) Why doesnt echo nl2br($row->comment); work? I put \n's into my database manually and it didn't output them. Testing\nTesting\nTesting came out as "Testing\nTesting\nTesting".

It should work as per the documentation: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

If it does not, please provide a PHP code sample demonstrating the issue

Comment: I've changed the type to blob, tried with a new input and left ($row->comment); the same, It's still not posted it with any formatting.  I've put an edit in with the PHP I used.  Cheers for the reply

Comment: Hi @JakeKirby, can you please do a `var_dump($row->comment);` in the `while()` and post the result?

Comment: string 'TestTestTest' (length=12)

Comment: It means that MySQL does not stores the `\n` in the first place. It might be because you use `PDO::PARAM_STR` in the insert and you could try to replace it with `PDO::PARAM_LOB` (see https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php). If that does not fixes it you should var dump `$sWall` before the insert to make sure it contains the line breaks.